# How to set partition in azure event hub consumer java code

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

i want to know the purpose of the hostname in EventProcessHost and how to set partition in consumer side . right now i am able to get data from consumer group but all partitions goes to the output stream .

Questions:
1.How to set partition via code java.
2.Use of hostname in EventProcessHost
3.example for multi consumer each has it's own partition in java code.

I highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complete Java example, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-receive-eph)

You don't need to set a partition when you use an `EventProcessHost`. Instead, each instance will lease a partition it will work on. So if you created the event hub using ,say 4 partitions, you should instantiate 4x `EventProcessHost` to get better troughput. See the linked docs as well:

> This tutorial uses a single instance of EventProcessorHost. To increase throughput, it is recommended that you run multiple instances of EventProcessorHost, preferably on separate machines. This provides redundancy as well. In those cases, the various instances automatically coordinate with each other in order to load balance the received events.

Leases are given out for a specific time only. After that another receiver can take over that lease. If you give it a while you should notice all instances will retrieve data.

About the hostname:

> When receiving events from different machines, it might be useful to specify names for EventProcessorHost instances based on the machines (or roles) in which they are deployed.

Comment: I am looking to solve a similar problem. I have an EventHub with 2 partitions. When I create a EventProcessorHost(EPH) to consume from this hub, it takes a lease on both the partitions. So, when a new instance of EPH is started, the first one exits with the error - " com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ReceiverDisconnectedException: New receiver with higher epoch of '2'...". Looking into the EPH code, I believe it uses AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager class by default to acquire leases to all the paritions in the event hub. Do you know if there is a way to run EPH in multiple process/machines?

Comment: Well, leases are given out for a specific time only. After that another receiver can take over that lease. If you give it a while you should notice both instances will retrieve data.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I am able to confirm that the lease spreads out between nodes after a while. Can you update your answer with this info? I will go ahead and upvote your answer.